# Refactoring: Dual Keys and generic methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I Have a few generic methods for constructing a Hibernate Search Model.

Basically it requires 2 keys and a few inputs. key1 !=key2

Example

```
public SearchModel getSearchModelA(String key1, String key2, List<String>)...

public SearchModel getSearchModelB(String key1, String key2, String input)...
```

May I know how should I refactor this class because

1) the client always need to provide 2 keys (best approach combine them?

Example of a caller

```
Helper.getSearchModelB(CONSTANTS.getKeyABC, CONSTANTS.getKeyABC,abc)
```

and the key can be quite long.

2) The class is getting too big and I like to keep my class below 1000 lines

I have already provided a static class with all the helper methods to create the `SearchModel` but the caller is a Facade and is messy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a List as your final parameter, you could use [varargs](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/using-the-varargs-language-feature.html):

```
public SearchModel getSearchModelA(String key1, String key2, String... input)
```

This would accept the single-string argument (but place it into a one-element array) or the multiple-string argument (represented as an array of String rather than a List).